# How to grep a file which is a string redirected from awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a script like this :

```
awk '{
some code here
print path | grep somekeyword
}'
```

In the script above, grep will just search the "path" itself as a string, but what I really want is to search the file the "path" string points to.

For example :

path is

> "/tmp/test.txt"

I want to search the content of **test.txt**, not the plain text **"/tmp/test.txt"**.

Is there some options of awk or grep can do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `grep somekeyword path` is the normal syntax

Comment: awk is a tool to manipulate text. A shell is an environment from which to call tools. Guess which one you should call grep from if you need it (hint: it's not awk). If you post some concise, testable sample input and expected output we can help you figure out how to do whatever it is you want to do the right way.

Comment: Did you want this?  `awk '{ some code here }' "/tmp/test.txt" |grep somekeyword`

Answer (score 0):

if there is a legitimate need, here is an example

```
awk 'BEGIN{cmd="grep keyword file"; cmd | getline result; print result}'
```

Comment: There's a few issues with using `getline` that way. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline for how to call getline safely IF it's required.